# DistinctBy when the property to distinct is a list

Tags: c#, linq, distinct

"Everyone" knows the usefull DistintBy extension from [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/), i need to use it to distinct a list os object by more than one property (no problem with it) and when one of this properties is a list, here is my custom class:

```
public class WrappedNotification
{
    public int ResponsibleAreaSourceId { get; set; }
    public int ResponsibleAreaDestinationId { get; set; }
    public List<String> EmailAddresses { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
}
```

In a test file a create some objects and try to distinct this items

```
List<WrappedNotification> notifications = new List<WrappedNotification>();
notifications.Add(new WrappedNotification(1, 1, new List<string>() { "email" }, EvaluationStatus.Approved, "group"));
notifications.Add(new WrappedNotification(0, 1, new List<string>() { "email" }, EvaluationStatus.Approved, "group"));
notifications.Add(new WrappedNotification(0, 1, new List<string>() { "email" }, EvaluationStatus.Approved, "group"));
notifications.Add(new WrappedNotification(0, 1, new List<string>() { "email" }, EvaluationStatus.Approved, "group"));
notifications.Add(new WrappedNotification(0, 1, new List<string>() { "email" }, EvaluationStatus.Approved, "group"));
```

Note that only the first item is different, so if i use the following code i can DistinctBy these items and the result list will have 2 items, and its ok.

```
 notifications = notifications.DistinctBy(m => new
 {
     m.ResponsibleAreaSourceId,
     m.ResponsibleAreaDestinationId,
     //m.EmailAddresses,
     m.EvalStatus
 }).ToList();
```

If i comment the line (//m.EmailAddresses) it dont work and returns me 5 items. How can i do this Distinct?

Comment: Why are you using `DistinctBy` when you're comparing your whole class?

Comment: What you want to achieve by commenting `EmailAddresses`?

Comment: You could just use the overload of `Distinct` that takes an `IEqualityComparer`, or use `string.Join` to create a string of emails in your anonymous class.

Comment: @Rawling: Most likely that is not the case. Compare the DistinctBy with the class declaration. It contains `EvalStatus` which is not declared in the class. From this I deduct that the OP shortened the class declaration and in reality it has more properties.

Answer (score 0):

`DistinctBy` uses the default equality comparer for every "key" you specify. The default equality comparer for `List<T>` just compares the references of the list itself. It doesn't check if the contents of the two lists are the same.

In your case `DistinctBy` is the wrong choice. You need to use `Enumerable.Distinct` and supply a custom `IEqualityComparer` that uses [`SequenceEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) on the email addresses.

Comment: good point, at this time i trying the approach sugested by @juharr and use the string.Join, later i will try to implement the IEqualityComparer that is more 'elegant' :)